# Issue running node.js on local 3000 host. It runs on my mac previously and now it doesn't

Tags: node.js, express

I have this [repository](https://github.com/kenneththesheep/project2_schoolResultManagement).

I have asked my friends to run on their localhost. It is working. But it is not working on my localhost. Every time I log in, it will be just hanging. It does not go into the dbpool in my code. Any advice will be good.

Comment: Try with another port. Let's see if its working or not with another port.

Comment: It is ok. I figured and resolved the issue. I have install something globally which affected my current project. So after uninstalling npm and reinstalling, it worked once again.